# Cannot Debug test given Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: debugging, spring-boot, gradle, jhipster

I have created a new project with Jhipster 4.10.2 , i have created the entities using JDL_Studio and i have following this [example to add additional info to the user](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html) .

At some point i am getting an error, and i would like to debug the applicaction, so for that I try to debug the test that is generated by Jhipster in java[test]/web/rest , but when I run the class in debug mode, i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/robertofernandez/Documents/myVoto_project/out/production/classes/com/mysmartcity/myvoto/service/impl/CategoriaServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mysmartcity.myvoto.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

When i run ./gradlew and after i run try to debug again i  get the following extra cause added to the one of before :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mysmartcity.myvoto.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

How can I solve this to be able to debug?

```java
package com.mysmartcity.myvoto.service.impl;

import com.mysmartcity.myvoto.service.CategoriaService;
import com.mysmartcity.myvoto.domain.Categoria;
import com.mysmartcity.myvoto.repository.CategoriaRepository;
import com.mysmartcity.myvoto.service.dto.CategoriaDTO;
import com.mysmartcity.myvoto.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Service Implementation for managing Categoria.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoriaServiceImpl implements CategoriaService{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoriaServiceImpl.class);

    private final CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository;

    private final CategoriaMapper categoriaMapper;

    public CategoriaServiceImpl(CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository, CategoriaMapper categoriaMapper) {
        this.categoriaRepository = categoriaRepository;
        this.categoriaMapper = categoriaMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Save a categoria.
     *
     * @param categoriaDTO the entity to save
     * @return the persisted entity
     */
    @Override
    public CategoriaDTO save(CategoriaDTO categoriaDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Categoria : {}", categoriaDTO);
        Categoria categoria = categoriaMapper.toEntity(categoriaDTO);
        categoria = categoriaRepository.save(categoria);
        return categoriaMapper.toDto(categoria);
    }

    /**
     *  Get all the categorias.
     *
     *  @return the list of entities
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<CategoriaDTO> findAll() {
        log.debug("Request to get all Categorias");
        return categoriaRepository.findAll().stream()
            .map(categoriaMapper::toDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    }

    /**
     *  Get one categoria by id.
     *
     *  @param id the id of the entity
     *  @return the entity
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public CategoriaDTO findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Categoria : {}", id);
        Categoria categoria = categoriaRepository.findOne(id);
        return categoriaMapper.toDto(categoria);
    }

    /**
     *  Delete the  categoria by id.
     *
     *  @param id the id of the entity
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Categoria : {}", id);
        categoriaRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Regards and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please add code of **categoriaServiceImpl** class.

Comment: @MehrajMalik by the way i did also the project from 0 with maven and i get the following error " UserExtraMapper.java:[18,18] No property named "user.name" exists in source parameter(s)." I think there is a bug with the generator when you extend the user entity